# how to load filename, filesize, reciveddate using SSIS, to a Database

Tags: ssis, metadata, etl

I am very new to the world of ETL, though I have done couple of ETL using SSIS  since I started learning ETL like 3 months ago. I have a good question for anybody with the experience.

. I want to populate a table in a database I created with files information ( Filename, FileSize and ReceivedDate ) from a folder. Using SSIS package. An example is loading file information in the path below in a sql database.

C:\Users\Documents\newfiles\purchaseorder. C:\Users\Documents\newfiles\invoice.

Also note I have multiple types of file. csv,edi,tcf etc.

Can anyone kindly give a step by step guide to solving this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This broad question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Please check out the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get that sort of information is to use the .NET Framework's `System.IO.FileInfo` class  in a Script Task:

```cs
   public void Main()
    {
        var receivedFile = (string)Dts.Variables["User::ReceivedFile"].Value;
        var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(receivedFile);
        Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value = fileInfo.FullName;
        Dts.Variables["User::FileSize"].Value = fileInfo.Length;
        Dts.Variables["User::ReceivedDate"].Value = fileInfo.CreationTime;
        // or whatever other information you may need

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

The code above assumes that you've set the `User::ReceivedFile` variable to the full path of whatever file you're dealing with; this is typically (but not always) done through a File System Task. Obviously, when configuring the Script Task, you'll need to specify `ReadWrite` access for the variables you'll be writing to.

Once you have that information in variables, of course, you can use it in whatever manner is needed.

For further information on the `FileInfo` class, see MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akth6b1k.aspx).

Comment: Thanks guys, I am trying them, I should have said it earlier that I have a little knowledge of C#, Also what if I have like 1000 files in a folder that I want the information. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

this is piece of code which I am using to extract the info...

```
     HHInfo = New FileInfo(HHFile(i).ToString())

    HHFileDate = HHInfo.CreationTime

  HHDate = HHFileDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    writer.Write("HHInfo.CreationTime  : " & HHInfo.CreationTime.ToString & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
                    writer.Write("HHInfo.LastAccessTime  : " & HHInfo.LastAccessTime.ToString & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
                    writer.Write("HHInfo.LastWriteTime  : " & HHInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)

                    HHElapsedTime = New DateTime(((HHInfo.LastWriteTime - HHInfo.CreationTime).Ticks))

                    EndTimelist.Add(HHInfo.LastWriteTime)

                    writer.Write("HHElapsedTime  : " & HHElapsedTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)

                    swriter.WriteLine("HH Start Time  : " & HHInfo.CreationTime.ToString & vbNewLine)
                    swriter.WriteLine("HH End Time  : " & HHInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString & vbNewLine)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I am trying them, I should have said it earlier that I have a little knowledge of C#, Also what if I have like 1000 files in a folder that I want the information. Thanks for your help